# hide/show google maps directionsService

Tags: google-maps

I have bus routes displays on a map using google map directionServices. Because many routes overlap I wish to be able to hide and show then with a click of a checkbox.

I have really unsure if they can be turned on/off like that.

```
function fiveCLine(source,destination,waypoints){
        // show route between the points
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
        {
            suppressMarkers: false,
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            polylineOptions: { strokeColor: '#0093f0', strokeOpacity: 1 },
            preserveViewport: true,
            markerOptions : {icon: 'bus5c.png'}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        var request = {
            origin:source, 
            destination:destination,
            waypoints:waypoints,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem relevant to your question. You're talking about bus routes but your code has travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING - Which one is it?

Comment: the other option I could have used is transit, but my city has no transit information. Driving is quite sufficient for displaying the route the bus takes. I jsut need a way to hide/show with a click of a check box.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using `setMap()` method of `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` class. From google docs: *This method specifies the map on which directions will be rendered. Pass `null` to remove the directions from the map.*

For example, I used button to toggle path:

```
function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  ...
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  ...

  var hideShowBtn = document.getElementById('togglePath');
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(hideShowBtn, 'click', hideShowPath);
}

function hideShowPath() {
    if (directionsDisplay.getMap()) {
        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    } else {
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }
}
```